# Knative suggested way to store binaries

Tags: persistent-volumes, binaries, knative

Knative does only support persistent volumes of type secret, configMap or projected. [Here](https://knative.tips/pod-config/volumes/) in the doc is mentioned a workaround to work with other persistent volumes.
It's not clear to me what is the suggested way, and not a workaround, to store binaries in a private cloud system, that does not rely on something like S3 or other cloud storages.

Marco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested way is to expose storage as an external service (SQL database, Redis, S3-compatible object storage like Minio or Ceph, or custom API).

If you're running a recent Knative build, there are [feature flags](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/main/config/core/configmaps/features.yaml#L156) which can enable PersistentVolumeClaims, but these shared filesystems can introduce scaling issues (and data corruption bugs, depending on locking implementation), so are not enabled by default.